# Ошибка с oauthlib oauth2 с nginx

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask, oauth, gunicorn

Есть сервер с единственным внешним ip (уже предлагали раскидать по серверам, не подходит такое решение), задача развести приложения flask по доменным именам.

Я уже настроил guicorn и Nginx, но столкнулся с ошибкой google oauth2 при подключенном nginx (без него все прекрасно работает). Возможно ошибка возникает при блокировке некоторых запросов, но это не точно.
Пользователь может авторизоваться, но после этого сразу вылетает.

### Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name app.ru;
    
        ssl_certificate <путь>/ssl/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key <путь>/ssl/key.pem;
        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass https://unix:<путь>/app.sock;
        }
    }
```

### Service Unit

```
[Unit]
Description=app
Requires=app.socket
After=network.target
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=<путь>
Environment="PATH=<путь>/venv/bin/"
ExecStart=gunicorn --workers 10 --certfile=ssl/cert.crt --keyfile=ssl/key.pem --user limb --group www-data -m 007 --bind unix:app.sock wsgi:app
Restart=always
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### Socket Unit

```
[Unit]
Description=socket

[Socket]
User=root
ListenStream=<путь>/app.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

### Код Авторизации

```
@app.route("/login")
def login():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
        authorization_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["authorization_endpoint"]
        request_uri = oauth.prepare_request_uri(
            authorization_endpoint,
            redirect_uri=request.base_url + "/callback",
            scope=["openid", "email", "profile"],
        )
        return redirect(request_uri)
    else:
        return redirect(profile)

@app.route("/login/callback")
def callback():
    if not current_user.is_authenticated:
        code = request.args.get("code")

        google_provider_cfg = get_google_provider_cfg()
        token_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["token_endpoint"]
        token_url, headers, body = oauth.prepare_token_request(
            token_endpoint,
            authorization_response=request.url,
            redirect_url=request.base_url,
            code=code
        )
        token_response = requests.post(
            token_url,
            headers=headers,
            data=body,
            auth=(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET),
        )
        oauth.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))

        userinfo_endpoint = google_provider_cfg["userinfo_endpoint"]
        uri, headers, body = oauth.add_token(userinfo_endpoint)
        userinfo_response = requests.get(uri, headers=headers, data=body)
        if userinfo_response.json().get("email_verified"):
            unique_id = userinfo_response.json()["sub"]
            users_email = userinfo_response.json()["email"]
            try:
                picture = userinfo_response.json()["picture"]
            except KeyError:
                picture = "/static/img/default-image.jpg"
            try:
                users_name = userinfo_response.json()["given_name"]
            except KeyError:
                flash("Аккаунт без имени. Регистрация запрещена.")
                return redirect("403")
            try:
                last_name = userinfo_response.json()["family_name"]
            except KeyError:
                flash("Аккаунт без фамилии. Регистрация запрещена.")
                return redirect("403")
        else:
            flash("Почта google не подтверждена. Регистрация запрещена.")
            return redirect("403")

        oauth.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))
        new_user = User(google=str(unique_id), username=users_name + ' ' + last_name, email=users_email, profile_img=picture)

        if User.query.filter_by(google=str(unique_id)).first() is None:
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_user)
            return redirect(request.url, code=302)
            make_logging("<auth> User sign in")
        else:
            login_user(User.query.filter_by(google=unique_id).first())
            db.session.commit()
            make_logging("<auth> User log in")
            return redirect(request.url, code=302)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for("main"))
```

### Ошибка в логах

```
    ERROR:app:Exception on /login/callback [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/limb/rossnou_stud_help_freelance/app/routes.py", line 114, in callback
    oauth.parse_request_body_response(json.dumps(token_response.json()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/clients/base.py", line 427, in parse_request_body_response
    self.token = parse_token_response(body, scope=scope)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 441, in parse_token_response
    validate_token_parameters(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py", line 448, in validate_token_parameters
    raise_from_error(params.get('error'), params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/errors.py", line 399, in raise_from_error
    raise cls(**kwargs)
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.InvalidGrantError: (invalid_grant) Bad Request
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.